# What scenes are these images from the Visual Dictionary from?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, princess-leia, deleted-scenes

The Visual Dictionary for Episode VII contains various shots that were not present in the final film. It is obvious that they were actual scenes that were cut from the theatrical release. I found two images that stood out to me which feature **Leia** talking:

---

[image]

[image]

---

The first image appears on Leia's page and the second one on Threepio's in the book. Does anybody know if these scenes actually appear in the novelisation? And if so, what they're about? I would assume that the first picture would be Leia giving the victory speech to the Resistance after Starkiller Base was eradicated, and the second one being simple exposition that was cut.

Answer (score 3):

### Leia addresses the Resistance

Fun fact: this scene is depicted on a Topps trading card, titled "Resistance Briefing":

[image]

Sadly the reverse of the card is as unhelpful in identifying the scene as the subtitle in the *Visual Dictionary*. Even more sadly, there appears to be no scene in the novelization (either version), nor any of the known deleted scenes, that corresponds to this one.

Most of the briefing scenes in the novel (and the film) take place in the map room (visible behind Leia in that image); this is where the briefing for the Starkiller attack takes place, for example. Other mission briefings we see are described as "huddled", rather than as Leia addressing a room.

Since there are no X-Wing pilots visible in that image, I would suggest that this scene is meant to take place either after the destruction of the Hosnian system, or before or after the attack on Starkiller Base, but I have no evidence to support either theory. As near as I can tell, this was a staged image for promotional purposes.

### Leia and Threepio

There two one-on-ones between Leia and Threepio that I found in the novelization, both pertaining to BB-8:

- The first takes place after Leia learns of the Jakku attack. She orders Threepio to locate BB-8:

  > General Organa turned to the droid in attendance. In sharp contrast to one arm that was a dull red, the bipedal machine's reflective golden torso gleamed from a recent cleaning.
  >
  > "See-Threepio, you've heard the information from Jakku. Locate Beebee-Ate immediately - you know what to do."
  >
  > Nodding slightly and gesturing with the red arm, the protocol droid responded without hesitation. "Yes, General! Of course! The tracking system. Oh dear, this is a calamity!"
  >
  > <sup>*The Force Awakens* Chapter X</sup>

  It's known that at least part of this scene was filmed and deleted; this scenes comes immediately after the scene titled "Jakku Message", which was [included](https://www.wired.com/2016/04/force-awakens-deleted-scenes/) on the April 2016 Blu-ray release
- The second comes somewhat later, when Threepio declares that they've found BB-8 on Takodana:

  > "Princess - I mean, General!" At the sound of the protocol droid's familiar voice, Leia turned and waved off the tech. "I hate to brag - as you know I was fitted with a humility circuit during my last rebuild, though I cannot imagine why anyone would think I would require such an accessory - but I must risk taking a moment of your time to sing my own praises!"
  >
  > "Threepio!" She didn't try to hide her exasperation. "No one has this kind of time!"
  >
  > "This kind of time was made for precisely this kind of intelligence, General," the droid insisted proudly. "I believe I have successfully located Beebee-Ate! According to the information I have just received through our scattered but attentive network, Beebee-Ate is presently within the castle of Maz Kanata on Takodana."
  >
  > <sup>*The Force Awakens* Chapter XI</sup>

The image could correspond to either scene or, really, any conversation between the two characters; without additional context, it's impossible to tell.